# How strong could the Coulomb force be made?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, electromagnetism

This is a pretty hypothetical question.  I was just reading about electromagnetism and about how two charges of one coulomb could repel/attract each other at a distance of one meter with some huge amount of force, like a million tons.  But this isn't seen because charges in, say, two wires because the charges generally are pretty much neutral.  So, could there hypothetically be a way to have large charges that repel or attract each other?  I mean, it seems like it could be possible but I'd have no idea how.

Comment: related: https://what-if.xkcd.com/140/ and further reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question is what do you want to design?

The coulomb-force is very small.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coulomb%27s_law

The theoretical very high force comes from a calculation where you would assume that you could separate many/most/all electrons from a piece of mass, leaving an extremely strongly charged body. But this is impossible and would cause a whole lot of other strange things. For example, the atoms in that body would repel each other, desintegrating the object.

https://gravityandlevity.wordpress.com/2013/05/22/what-if-i-were-1-charged/

I reality, the electric charge is mostly neutral, leaving you the the low real-life measurable coulomb-forces, even when charging something with electric potential of some kV.

Comment: before disintegration I would expect a discharge (lightning). Also however you are sorting the charges is expected to get harder the more you do it to the point where it doesn't work anymore.